# Is asking about how to get information from a specific site effectively on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

An example question: [Do I need to pay money to attracting people interact with me in language exchange sites?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1066/961)

I'm a trivial user on the internet, who are not a mod or admin in any site except my blog. Therefore, my main interest is about the user's perspective of the sites. I only go to a site if I can be sure that it is informative. So if I'm unable to get the information that supposed to be there, can I ask how in here? Is this kind of questions on-topic or constructive?

In a very related question, [Are questions asking for information about top techniques used by major sites on topic?](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/108/961), only Henderson's answer answers my question here, and he agrees they are good subjective. The two others are just responses for the deleted question linked at the start.

Some more example for this kind of questions:

- How to get desired information on Reddit effectively?
- How to search for the right subreddit? (it's different from [top ten subreddits](http://bestsubreddits.com/).)
- Can communities whose contents are only valuable within a couple hours work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking a step back, yes **[questions from the user's perspective are OK](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/should-we-accept-questions-about-moderation-issues-from-users-points-of-view)** (ignore that the linked question mentions moderation: that was before our name change).

However, the real question still needs a little attention.

Looking at the question, it actually doesn't seem to be focused on getting something out of the content; it seems to be about creating interaction. I think that creating interaction with others is really what you want to know, and that's on topic. The money aspect shouldn't be the main point of the question since I'm assuming that you'd be open to other possibilities, but it definitely could be suggested in the body of the question. At least to me, it's more of a wording issue with the question than the actual message. Editing would ensure that discussion stays relevant, on topic, and helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have removed the money out of the title. Should we edit the linked question from your answer to reflect the new policy? And should we make an on-topic-ness tag?

Comment: @Ooker the "scope" tag is used for discussing what is on topic and what isn't. The other link is fine: it's not really a new policy and the moderation-specifics of it isn't an essential part of the answer.

Comment: Even it's not an essential part, should we edit its title to make it less confusing?